# Magento 2 : Check before Cart Price Rules Applies

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart

I have been looking for **event** || **Plugin** || **Whatsoever** !!

I have a rule that will apply to the customer only one time, **without using coupon code**.

I am willing to add some conditional statements before that **discount**(Cart Price Rule) applied to customer cart.

How to do that? what's possible way?

**UPDATE**

I am trying to find a way to give the discount to users who subscribe to our newsletter.

**If they subscribed to the newsletter than they will get $5 fixed price discount on their first purchase without using any coupon code.**

Comment: Can you explain the question a bit more?

Comment: I've added more details Mohit please check. Give me some guide.

Comment: Means you want to show some kind of message if the discount applies. Am I right?

Comment: No need for message Also no need for coupon code , Just need to give discount of $5, If user/customer is subscribed and cart total is greater than $30.

Comment: I have posted my answer. Please check and let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a custom module to provide a particular discount on first order if the user has subscribed to the newsletter.

Since the module has many files, I could not post the code here.

Please check this [link](https://github.com/mohitka/NewsletterDiscountMagento2) to download the module.

**Update: condition for checking subtotal**

> 1. Open app/code/Stack/NewsletterDiscount/Model/Total/Quote/NewsletterDiscount.php and find code like this:

```
if ( !$program->getId() || !$this->service->canGetDiscount($email) ) {
```

> 2. Replace it with:

```
if ( !$program->getId() || !$this->service->canGetDiscount($email, $subtotal) ) {
```

> 3. Get the value of subtotal in variable **`$subtotal`** before above condition.
> 4. Now open app/code/Stack/NewsletterDiscount/Model/Service.php and change the line:

```
public function canGetDiscount($email) {
```

to

```
public function canGetDiscount($email, $amount) {
```

> 5. In the same file find below code:

```
if ( $isValidSubscriber && $discountTimes < $maxTimes ) {
```

and replace above line of code with:

```
if ( $isValidSubscriber && $discountTimes < $maxTimes && $amount > 30) {
```

Please follow the instructions in the readme file and let me know if it helped.

Comment: Thanks for your time, Your work is amazing but I need to give discount only if subtotal is above 30 How can i do with this ?

Comment: @TBSMage, please check my updated answer. Above steps are for hint only. You will need to write code as per your requirement.